# Unable to log in to tty1 password incorrect?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password, console, authentication

In the console tty1 I can't access with my login and password. It states that my password is incorrect however my password is correct?

Comment: I'd rather trust the error message. Are you sure you didn't mistype (caps lock?)? Do you have other means to login? Or to modify your password.

Comment: Hello RudiC,  yes I'm sure but how can i show the list of users. thanks

Comment: After GRUB i have the error message: De graves erreurs ont été trouvées lors de la vérification du disque pour /boot.
Appuyer sur I pour ignorer, S pour ignorer le montage ou M pour la récupération manuelle.     maybe there is a relationship?

Comment: The message seems to indicate the system had problems mounting the `/boot` filesystem. If you select M, it might give you a shell prompt with direct root access - or perhaps prompt for a password of any user with admin rights, if it's been changed to be more secure than it was the last time I had a chance to see Ubuntu in recovery mode. And if the system is in the normal console `login:` prompt, there is no way to show a list of users without logging in first.

Comment: i tried following commands:

sudo mount -o remount,rw /
sudo  dpkg --configure -a
sudo mount -o remount,ro /
sudo sync
sudo reboot

Comment: but nothing is changing please Help me

Comment: @menyarito Have you tried tty2, tty3? Which ubuntu version do you mean?

Comment: What happened when you selected  "M pour la récupération manuelle"

Comment: Finally I install a new version. thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're **typing** your password correctly? Check whether the keyboard layout is what you expect (type at the login prompt). The text console and the graphical user interface use different means to configure the keyboard.

To change the console keymap, run `loadkeys` with the keymap name, e.g. `loadkeys fr` to load a French keymap. This takes effect until the next time the keymap is changed or until the next reboot. All text consoles use the same keymap.

On modern distributions, you can configure the default console keymap through systemd. (Some distributions may have other mechanisms as well, it's a bit of a mess.) You can see the current setting with

```
localectl status
```

in the `VC keymap` line, and change it with `localectl set-keymap --no-convert`.

Comment: ii think my problem is because the following two message error: 1.les entrés de la table de partitions ne sont pas dans oredre du disque.
2.e2fsck : Veuillez obtenir une version plus récente d'e2fsck !

Comment: Based on your comments, your system disk is corrupted. Anything could happen. Get a new disk and restore from a known good backup or reinstall.